# Cannot see own created temapltes in openshift via OC commands

Tags: openshift

Developer Catalog have dozens of templates provided by default & After creating own custom templates either via openshift console or via oc create command the teamplate when listed does not shows up which are self created.

```
$ oc get templates -n openshift
```

Lists all default teamplates but does not appers the self created one.

After creating from oc command like below:

```
$ oc create -f testtemplate.json
```

This also does not list the created template.

Please suggest any clue if there is any restrictions on it & path forward.

Comment: Please update your question to in clude the template manifest, and also the output of `kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{..namespace}'` (to show which namespace will be used by default if you don't use `-n <namespace>` on the create/apply command line).

Answer (score 1):

You Should add the default namespace on the question.
Otherwise, might using the `-n` option with the name of the project `-n <namespace>` to list/create templates.

```
-- Create template
$ oc create -f testtemplate -n target-namespace

-- Listing all templates in target-namespace project
$ oc get templates -n target-namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

How about add annotations for metadata to your custom template like existing Templates ? Refer [Writing the template description](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/openshift_images/using-templates.html#templates-writing-description_using-templates) for more details.